# How to convert exponential number(SimpleXML object string) to decimal in PHP

Tags: php, soap, simplexml, exponential

I am making a SOAP call to fetch some data from server and am reading that using SimpleXML extension available in PHP. Now, in amount field I am getting value such as this `2.796565248E9` and used `round` or `number_format` function to convert it to whole/decimal number, but it is giving me result as `2` only.

Now, I am getting multiple amount values from that SOAP call. And I am getting amount values such as `2.796565248E9`, `200.0`, `2000.0`. When I use `round` or `number_format` function, I get proper value for `200.0` and `2000.0` like `200` and `2000` respectively. But for `2.796565248E9`, I am getting only `2` only, not `2796565248`, which is expected.

First I was confused, but when I dump that variable i.e. `$value->amount` which holds this value, I got this response

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#354 (1) {
  [0]=>  string(13) "2.796565248E9"
}
```

Now, I think because of this it is not showing desired result. Kindly guide me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you're passing to `round` needs to be cast to float before the function runs, either explicitly by your code, or implicitly by the PHP engine. If you pass in a string, it will be coerced to a float automatically, but if you pass in an object - such as the `SimpleXMLElement` you have here - it gets cast to an int instead.

This is because of an issue with PHP's internals, filed as [PHP bug #53033](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53033) (and a few near-duplicates), which it looks like [Nikita Popov has fixed for PHP 7.3](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/b2b2b437af5495dcb2016be6e45567ed826cb87e). Basically, the engine had no way to ask an object with custom conversion code for "a number", so it could not choose smartly between a float and an int.

In the meantime, explicitly casting to float, e.g.`$value = round( (float)$my_object, $precision );` will avoid the issue.

Casting to string would also work, because the engine knows it should convert a string to a float in this situation, so it can be a useful general habit to add `(string)` in front of elements and attributes as you extract them from SimpleXML. This also avoids other issues, such as accidentally trying to serialize the object in a session, or keeping the XML in memory for longer than necessary because it's accessible from some value object.

Answer (score 1):

**Try round() with a second arg which is an offset for values after decimal :-**

```
round(2.79656,2)
```

**You can refer to this link :-**
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_round.asp

Comment: Maybe you are trying to round-up string not an integer/float value. Did you try converting the string (in your case) to int/float and then rounding up ?

Comment: W3Schools is slightly less awful than it used to be, but for PHP functions, the official reference on php.net is generally a better resource. e.g. in this case http://php.net/round I notice the w3schools [description of the non-existent `delete` function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_delete.asp) still exists, but appears to no longer be linked from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Using `(float)` will help. Try following code:

```
<?php
$scientific_str="2.796565248E9";
$scientific_num=(float) $scientific_str;
var_dump($scientific_num);
```

Comment: It worked. I am quite sure that I tried `(float)` also, but it didn't work or I might have overlooked that. But glad your solution worked. Any idea, why `round` function is not working in my scenario?

Comment: It's strange. `round` should also work. I tried `echo round('2.796565248E9');`, it also gives the same result.

Comment: If I use this `echo round('2.796565248E9');`, I get desired answer. But I don't know, why it is not working in my scenario, where I am reading data from xml. Always getting `2`. Need expert advise on it.

Comment: @TonyMontana Thinking about it, that should perhaps be an answer to the original question, so I've moved it into one.